# How do you attach another database and successfully import data from a python script SQL Lite?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

So I'm connecting to SQLite through python's sqlite3 module. I am creating table nutrient in meal_planner.db and I want to import specific columns from nutr_def in another SQLite database I created (usda.db); I did this same project successfully before in SQL and want to replicate that functionality. Even though the code ran without errors, a check of the databases revealed that while the table (nutr_def) in the usda database is correctly populated with data, the table in meal_planner (nutrient) is empty. The data was not imported correctly and I don't know why - this code should be simple. Any insight is appreciated!

Original SQL code whose functionality I'm trying to replicate:

```
drop database if exists meal_plan;
create database meal_plan
character set'latin1'
collate 'latin1_swedish_ci';

drop table if exists meal_plan.nutrient;
create table meal_plan.nutrient 
    as (select Nutr_No as nutrient_id,
    nutrdesc as nutrient_name,
    units as units from usda.nutr_def);
```

Python script to create SQLite Database:

```
import sqlite3

database_name = 'meal_planner.db'
db = sqlite3.connect(database_name)

db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row

cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("attach database 'usda.db' as usda")
cursor.execute("drop table if exists nutrient")
cursor.execute("create table nutrient(nutrient_id, nutrient_name, units)")
cursor.execute("insert into nutrient select Nutr_No, nutrdesc, units from usda.nutr_def")
```

[database usda, data in table nutr_def][image: 2]

[database meal_planner, data in table nutrient after running code (it's empty)][image: 3]

Comment: please paste code as text instead of screenshots

Comment: just finished! thanks!

Comment: i did not see statement for commit `execute("commit")` . pls check if your code has step to `commit' .